# Restify won't listen on ipv6

Tags: restify

Using the sample server from restify's README, it starts up and binds to port 8080 on the ipv4 address only. Is there a way to get it to bind to all the addresses? Mac OS X.

```
$ node test.js
myapp listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080

$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp4       0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

It's slightly annoying because 'localhost' tries the v6 address first, and some clients (eg: curl) do not try other addresses. I have to remember to always type 127.0.0.1 explicitly.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/
{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/ does not exist"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the message `myapp listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080` comes from something like this in your `test.js`

```
app.listen(8080, function(err) {
  console.log("myapp listening at %s", app.url);
});
```

Instead use this:

```
app.listen(8080, '::', function(err) {
  console.log("myapp listening at %s", app.url);
});
```

This will make node.js listen on both IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces. Tested OK using modules `express` and `restify`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! On which node versions should it work?